# European wattmeter symbol

Tags: circuitikz

I am very new at circuitikz.  I have most of the european symbols I need, but now I need to make this simple wattmeter symbol and I do not know how.

One could start with the european voltage source symbol.  The horizontal line inside the circle should also be thicker than the example to clearly show the current coil.

Any help would be very nice.

[image: wattmeter in circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a symbol; the only wattmeter in `circuitikz` is this:

[image]

But you can use the `rmeter` (or even `rmeterwa` if you fancy the metering arrow):

[image]

For example like this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \draw (0,0) |- ++(1,1) to[rmeter, name=W] ++(2,0);
    % add the lines to the rmeter
    \draw [very thick] (W.west) -- (W.east);
    \draw (W.north) -- (W.south);
    % leads
    \draw (0,0) to[short, *-] (W.south|- 0,0) -- (W.south);
    \draw (W.north) |- ++(1,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a long comment to the accepted answer above.

Please vote if you agree that the symbols below would be useful!

[image]

I propose a uniform set of symbols for active- reactive- and apparent power meters as below as well as restricting ammeters and voltmeters in the same circuits to those above.  Sample code (bad sample code) follows:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Overall font to Times New Roman
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% Add a period (.) after the clause numbering (in the actual document, NOT toc)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line
%\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\tikzset{voltage dir = RP}
%\usetikzlibrary{external} 
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,optimize command away=\includepdf]

\usepackage{pgf,siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\SendSettingsToPgf

\usepackage{steinmetz} %for phase angles
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\phase}{#2}{\vphantom{,}#2}{}{}

\usepackage[iso,english]{isodate}
\renewcommand*\date[1]{{\isodate{#1}}}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
% omit page numbers from citations
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\input{terms}
\input{abbrv}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareSIUnit\kVA{kVA}
% \mbf bold upright math 
% \mbs bold italic math 
\makeatletter 
  \AtBeginDocument{% 
  % For mtpro2 users, switch \mathbold to \mbs
  \@ifpackageloaded{mtpro2}{\let\mbs\mathbold}{\let\mbs\bm} 
  % For non-mtpro2 users, switch \mbf to \mathbf
  \@ifpackageloaded{mtpro2}{}{\let\mbf\mathbf} } 
\makeatother
\renewcommand\vec{\bm}
\def\j{\ensuremath{\mbf{j}}}
\def\Z{\ensuremath{\vec{Z}}}
\def\u{\ensuremath{\vec{u}}}
\def\i{\ensuremath{\vec{i}}}
\def\S{\ensuremath{\vec{S}}}
\def\aa{\ensuremath{\mbf{a}}}
\def\a{\ensuremath{\vec{a}}}
\def\b{\ensuremath{\vec{b}}}
\def\c{\ensuremath{\vec{c}}}
\def\cc{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{^*}}}
\def\A{\ensuremath{\vec{A}}}
\def\B{\ensuremath{\vec{B}}}
\def\C{\ensuremath{\vec{C}}}
\def\U{\ensuremath{\vec{U}}}
\def\I{\ensuremath{\vec{I}}}
\def\Re{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Re}}}
\def\Im{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Im}}}
\def\d{\ensuremath{\mathrm{d}}}
\def\rms{\ensuremath{\mathrm{RMS}}} % see IEC 60050 effective value
\def\eff{\ensuremath{\mathrm{eff}}}
\def\pf{\ensuremath{\mathrm{pf}}}
\def\E{\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}}}
\def\e{\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}
\def\ohm{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\Omega}}}
\def\ac{a.c.\,}
\def\dc{d.c.\,}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    { % power meter, active -  P [W], reactive - Q [var] and apparent - \S [VA]
      % proposed unified symbol for use - also Q1-Q4 implied in symbol
      % the diagonal link symbol might also be angular or omitted.
    \draw (0.5,5) to [open] (1,5) to [rmeter, name=W,i_=$I_a$] ++(1.8,0);
    \draw [very thick] (W.west) -- (W.east);
    \draw (W.north) to [open] (W.south) node[anchor=south]{\scriptsize[\si{VA}]};
    \draw (W.west) ++(-0.5,0)  to [short, o-] (W.east) to [short, -o] ++(0.5,0);
    \draw (W.west) to[short,l={$\S_a$}] (W.east);
    \draw (W.south) ++(0,-0.5)  to [short, o-] (W.south) (W.north) to [short, -o] ++(0,+0.5);
    \draw ($(W.north)+(0,+0.25)$) to [short, *-*] ($(W.west)-(0.25,0)$) ;
    \draw ($(W.south)-(0,0.5)$) to [open, v>=~, voltage shift=1.0] ($(W.north)+(0,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(W.north)+(0.25,0.25)$) node[anchor=west]{$U_a$};
    }
    { % voltmeter All voltmeters are vertically connected
    \draw (3,5) to [open] (3.15,5) to [rmeter, name=U,] ++(0.85,0);
%    \draw [very thick] (W.west) -- (W.east);
    \draw (U.north) to [open] (U.south) node[anchor=south]{\scriptsize[\si{V}]};
%    \draw (U.west) ++(-0.5,0)  to [short, o-] (W.east) to [short, -o] ++(0.5,0);
    \draw ($(U.west)+(0.2,0)$) to [short,l={$U_a$}] ($(U.east)-(0.2,0)$);% package error when open!!!!
    \draw (U.south) ++(0,-0.5)  to [short, o-] (U.south) (U.north) to [short, -o] ++(0,+0.5);
%    \draw ($(U.north)+(0,+0.25)$) to [short, *-*] ($(U.west)-(0.25,0)$) ;
    \draw ($(U.south)-(0,0.5)$) to [open, v>=~, voltage shift=1.0] ($(U.north)+(0,0.5)$);
    \draw ($(U.north)+(0.25,0.25)$) node[anchor=west]{$U_a$};
    }
    { % ammeter All ammeters are vertically connected
    \draw (4.0,5) to [open] (4.5,5) to [rmeter, name=A,i_=$I_a$] ++(1.8,0);
    \draw [very thick] (A.west) -- (A.east);
    \draw (A.north) to [open] (A.south) node[anchor=south]{\scriptsize[\si{A}]};
    \draw (A.west) ++(-0.5,0)  to [short, o-] (A.east) to [short, -o] ++(0.5,0);
    \draw (A.west) to[short,l={$I_a$}] (A.east);
%    \draw (A.south) ++(0,-0.5)  to [short, o-] (A.south) (A.north) to [short, -o] ++(0,+0.5);
%    \draw ($(A.north)+(0,+0.25)$) to [short, *-*] ($(A.west)-(0.25,0)$) ;
%    \draw ($(A.south)-(0,0.5)$) to [open, v>=~, voltage shift=1.0] ($(A.north)+(0,0.5)$);
%    \draw ($(A.north)+(0.25,0.25)$) node[anchor=west]{$\U_a$};
    }
    { circuitikz ammeter - not IEC
%    \draw (0.5,0) to [open] (1,0) to [ammeter, name=A, i_=$I_a$] ++(2,0);
    }
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```